# possible to use math.max for array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I see answers like this for getting the biggest number in an array,

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var max = Math.max(...arr);
```

But what about doing this for an array of objects, each of which have a number field, something like this

```
class test {
   number: x
   other_fields
}

var arr = [test1, test2, test3];
var max = Math.max(...arr);
```

Comment: No. But you can use `.map` to create an array of numbers from the array of objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.map` to transform the array of objects into an array of numbers first:

```
var max = Math.max(
  ...arr.map(obj => obj.number)
);
```

```js
const obj1 = {
   number: 2,
   prop: 'val'
};
const obj2 = {
   number: 2,
   prop: 'val'
};

var arr = [obj1, obj2];
var max = Math.max(
  ...arr.map(obj => obj.number)
);
console.log(max);
```

If you need an object and not just the number, use `reduce` instead:

```js
const obj1 = {
   number: 2,
   prop: 'val'
};
const obj2 = {
   number: 2,
   prop: 'val'
};

var arr = [obj1, obj2];
const largestObj = arr.reduce((a, obj) => a.number > obj.number ? a : obj);
console.log(largestObj);
```

Comment: but I need to get the whole object returned, is this possible?